# Is it possible to disconnect from and reconnect to remote X clients?

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, aws-cloud9

I'm basically trying to recreate the environment that Cloud9 provides - a work session with an editor and terminals which can be disconnected from and reconnected to from any PC. I have set up a server with X and SSH installed, and I can launch graphical applications like gVim remotely. The next issue is to be able to disconnect from the gVim instance and reconnect to it from a different computer.

Is this possible? Assuming the answer isn't "no", how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use tmux/screen to have persistent terminal sessions, or [Xpra](https://www.xpra.org/) to provide persistent X sessions, it works quite well for me. In many distros the packages are available out of the box (I am using Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Xpra looks really cool, but I can't get it to work. I'll give it another shot later